# Is it correct to say "I don't have time"

Tags: sentence-meaning

I know that this is correct:

> I haven't got time.

But is this sentence also correct?

> I don't have time

Comment: You don't necessarily need either of the auxiliary verbs ***do*** or ***got*** - you can also just say *I haven't time*. But note that some dialectal speakers (AAVE, for example) might think that shorter version is somehow "affected, lah-de-dah".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I thought "Have you a pen?" and "I have not time" are only used by BrE speakers.

Comment: @Cardinal: Don't get too enamoured of that simplistic US/UK distinction. In actual fact, Google Ngrams suggests Americans are actually slightly *more* likely than Brits to say, for example, [Have you no shame?](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+you+no+shame&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20you%20no%20shame%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 3):

*Have* and *have got* (and *have gotten*) are used differently in British English and American English— in fact, it is one of the [key distinctions](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/british-english-and-american-english) between the two, though the American forms have reportedly become more common in the UK. Some examination is covered in *[What do "have", "get" and "got" mean?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/47191)* as well as *[What do you have to say for yourself? / What have you got to say for yourself?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37174)* . Also see at EL&U, *[“have” vs.“have got” in American and British English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120721)* and many others.

The Separated by a Common Language blog, by a University of Sussex linguist, offers a [quick overview](http://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.com/2011/05/do-you-havehave-youhave-you-got.html) of *do you have* versus *have you got* for asking about possession. A search on corpora returned these frequencies:

> AmE: Do you have = 3092, Have you got = 99.  So 31:1.
>     BrE:  Do you have = 245, Have you got = 450.  So 1:<2.

In summary, she concludes

> - If you are on a UK street corner, say *Have you got a pineapple?*
> - If you are on a US street corner, say *Do you have a pineapple?*
> - If you say *Have you a pineapple?*, you risk assault for non-normative behavio(u)r.

---

Separately, it's not clear what your example sentences mean. As noted in *[Do you have a / the time?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8030)*, if you mean you are unaware of the time of day, you would say *the time* as another answer has indicated. It can also be used if referring to some known block of time, e.g. *I don't have the time to discuss this at the moment*. But the zero article can be appropriate if referring to time as an uncountable property, thus *I don't have time to discuss this at the moment*.

Comment: Flipping between [BrE and AmE corpuses](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+haven%27t+time%2CI+don%27t+have+time%2CI+haven%27t+got+time&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20have%20not%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20do%20not%20have%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20have%20not%20got%20time%3B%2Cc0) suggests the preference for including an auxiliary verb (*I don't have time* rather than *I haven't time*) only became the norm in the UK a couple of decades ago, and it was only a couple of decades before *that* that US usage shifted decisively.

Comment: @FumbleFingers And of course, I tend to write, if not say, *I haven't got time* in the so-called "British" fashion. Lynneguist has a linked post on [contracted *have*](http://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.com/2007/04/contracted-have.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct. You could also say:

> I haven't got **the** time.
>   I don't have **the** time.

Or replace *the* with *any*, *enough*, or *sufficient*, or a number of other similar words.

Answer (score 0):

In Britain, there are three structures for negatuves:

I haven't time.

I haven't got time.

I don't have time

In the U.S. people normally use the auxiliary do:

I don't have time.

So both the sentences presented by the OP are correct grammatically.